# how to create a simple popup window displaying only text, on a web site

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not a programmer, I've created a web site using a major hosting service's application. I want to insert code into a box provided by the hosting service that allows you to paste any HTML code.

I want to create a link on the site that opens a popup window to display text that I hard-code into the code. I don't want to jump to another HTML page.

I found the following code below that allows me to jump to another HTML page (it was set to CNN.com as an example). Is there a way to replace the action of jumping to another HTML page, with opening the popup and displaying the following example text "hello world". (please note in the code below, I deleted the opening and closing "a" tags at the beginning and end of the code since their inclusion causes problems when I type this question out on this web site).

```
<a href="http://www.cnn.com" onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://www.cnn.com','1426494439650','width=440,height=300,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;">Pop-up Window</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: You omitted the `<a>...</a>` tags around the sample code of your example.  I've added them in for you.  As for the question, you cannot use the example that you've given to do what you want as "window.open" is a function to open up a new window and retrieve the contents from another URL (e.g. cnn).  There are a number of ways you can do what you want although it would be helpful to know your "hosting service's application"

Comment: Did you tryied `alert(string);` JavaScript method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can place the function in the `<head>` section OR you can pull the function from a .js file. This will open a window and load the url you want. It won't redirect the original page as you use the # instead of the actual url.
 
`<script>
function popup(){
window.open('http://www.cnn.com','1426494439650','width=440,height=300,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0')
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="popup()">link</a>`

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please provide some additional information to your solution

Answer (score 0):

Easy to make popup window without Jquery. Just copy this code and paste. and clicl the open text. Popup shown.

```
    <p>To display the box, click on the link <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('shadowing').style.display='block';
          document.getElementById('box').style.display='block';">open</a> 
    </p>
 <div id="shadowing"></div>
    <div id="box">
       <span id="boxclose" onClick="document.getElementById('box').style.display='none';
       document.getElementById('shadowing').style.display='none'">close </span>
 <div id="boxcontent">    
    And this is the static content of the box. <br><br>
    Dynamic content in the next demo...    
    </div>
 </div>

    <style type="text/css">
    #shadowing{display: none;position: fixed;top: 0%;left: 0%;width: 100%;height: 100%; background-color: #CCA; z-index:10;    opacity:0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);}
    #box {display: none;position: fixed;top: 20%;left: 20%;width: 60%;height: 60%;max-height:400px;padding: 0; margin:0;border: 1px solid black;background-color: white;z-index:11; overflow: hidden;}   
    #boxclose{float:right;position:absolute; top: 0; right: 0px; background-image:url(images/close.gif);background-repeat:no-repeat;    background-color:#CCC; border:1px solid black; width:20px;height:20px;margin-right:0px;}
    #boxcontent{position:absolute;top:23px;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;margin:0 0 0 0;padding: 8px;overflow: auto;width:100%;height:100%;   overflow:hidden;}
    </style>
```